# How to get property values from same object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have this in javascript

```
var x = {
    "a" : function(q) { return q+1; },
    "b" : function(w) { return (this["a"])(1); } 
};
```

I want to do something, like access functions from the same object but different properties.
For example, in the above code, property `a` should be fine, but in property `b`, I want to use the function stored in `a`. Currently for fun I just have `this["a"]` which probably doesn't work. But is there a way I can get that function?

Thanks

Comment: You have my 1001st vote. Congratulations. Wait… no. The user says that I have 871 votes, while the review>badge thing says 1001… Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have actually works. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38Fjz/) here with your object..

**Javascript**

```
var x = {
    "a" : function(q) { return q+1; },
    "b" : function(w) { return (this["a"])(1); } 
};

document.body.innerHTML = x.b();
```

The result from calling `x.b()` is 2.

More complex objects can do it to like:

```js
var myObj = {
    myFunction: function(testVar)
    {
        return this.Utilities.helperFunction(testVar);
    },
    Utilities: {
        helperFunction: function(anotherVar)
        {
            return anotherVar * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

You may also notice that in this second example I use a different syntax for getting the property of the object. You can use either `this["a"]` or `this.a` which both return the same result. The reason you would use `this["a"]` is when you want to pass a variable in to grab the property or function.

[More information on the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: A whole lot cleaner to just use `this.a(1)`.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I just copied the example he had. Check my second example where I use that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to print it to the display:

```
var x = {
        "a" : function(q) {
            return q+1;
        },

        "b" : function(w) {
            return (this.a)(1);
        }
    };

    document.write(x.b(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

see this awesome overview of this: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

it goes one level up the chain; inside a function, `this` is the next level of scope above function, so in the case of `x.b=function() {this //}`, `this` looks 1 level up the scope and gets to `x`.